# sphinx error connection to 127.0.0.1:9845 failed (errno=0, msg=)

Tags: linux, search, centos, sphinx

i install sphinx in Centos,  all is correct

```
[root@li561-40 ~]# /usr/local/sphinx/bin/search crusher
Sphinx 2.0.6-release (r3473)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf'...
index 'test1': query 'crusher ': returned 1 matches of 1 total in 0.009 sec

displaying matches:
1. document=2, weight=2500, id_attr=2, date_added=Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
    ID=2
    crawl_date=0000-00-00 00:00:00
    host=(NULL)
    url=(NULL)
    page_title=crusher for sale
    page_content=this is content, stone crusher machine for sale
    parent=0
    status=publish
    type=page
    mime_type=

words:
1. 'crusher': 1 documents, 2 hits
```

but, when i use php api, it say connection to 127.0.0.1:9845 failed (errno=0, msg=)

```
require ( "sphinxapi.php" );
$s = new SphinxClient();
$s->SetServer('localhost',9312);

$result = $s->Query('crusher');
echo $s->getLastError();


[root@li561-40 ~]# netstat -anl | grep 9312
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9312                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

please tell me, what i should do ?

Comment: Where does 9845 come from? Your example is using port 9312. Try also using `netstat -nlp` which will tell you the program listening on that port.

Comment: sorry,  not 9845, is 9312, also error.  netstat -nlp   is correct

Comment: netstat -nlp | grep 9312   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9312              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      19601/searchd